# How to use options in transaction writes in react with firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have to use merge option in the below code, but didn't find a way, how to do it?

```js
import { runTransaction } from "firebase/firestore";

try {
  await runTransaction(db, async (transaction) => {
    transaction.set(doc(db, 'users', auth.currentUser.uid), {
        referenceNo: "1RIK93029JDH8JU",
    }, `OPTIONS`)
// How do I add options in the above query.
} catch (e) {
  console.log("Transaction failed: ", e);
}
```

**Option I want to use is merge option**

Comment: Replace `\`OPTIONS\`` by `{ merge: true }` like `set()` without a transaction? What's the issue in this case?